# H5 is embedded in Flutter, and the camera function in H5 cannot be used

Tags: flutter

H5 is embedded in Flutter, the camera function in H5 cannot be used, but the camera function can be used when H5 runs alone in the browser, what is the reason for this problem? How to solve?

I have configured the relevant permissions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.